# How can I discriminate between functions in R

Tags: r, classification

I have been trying to write a code capable of using different classification functions. However, the arguments are different depending on the classification function I use. I would like to have something like this :

```
classification_flow <- function(classification_function, ...) {
    if (classification_function == randomForest) {
        ...
    } 
    else if (classification_function == svm) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work since `==` wasn't built for functions. I've tried using `str`, `names`, `attr`, and looked a bit at `methods`and `UseMethod`, but I can't find a suitable way to do so.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Jess

PS : In this particular case, what I'm trying to do is to get a matrix of probabilities as the output, so something like that :

```
classification_flow <- function(classification_function, train, classes, ...) {
    if (classification_function == randomForest) {
        mat = classification_function(train, classes, type="prob")
    } 
    else if (classification_function == svm) {
        mat = classification_function(train, classes, probabilities = T)
    }
    return(mat)
}
```

If you know a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that can get a character or a function. Then you can do character comparisons to find the right case.

```
classification_flow <- function(classification_function, train, classes, ...) {
    if (is.function(classification_function)) {     
        fname <- deparse(substitute(classification_function))
    } else if (is.character(classification_function)) {
        fname <- classification_function
        classification_function < - get(classification_function)
    } else {
        stop("invalid classification_function")
    }

    if (fname == "randomForest") {
        mat = classification_function(train, classes, type="prob")
    } 
    else if (fname == "svm") {
        mat = classification_function(train, classes, probabilities = T)
    }
    return(mat)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `substitute`:

```
f <- function(x, FUN) {
  if (substitute(FUN) == 'max') {
    print('Max invoked')
  }
  FUN(x)
}

> f(1:4, sum)
[1] 10
> f(1:4, max)
[1] "Max invoked"
[1] 4
```

Comment: but do `g = max` then `f(1:4, g)` and you'll be disappointed. I think the use of a character `method` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First, make the input to `classification_function` a character input.

Then, use the `switch` function to chose between your two options like so:

```
classification_flow <- function(classification_function, train, classes, ...) {
switch(classification_function,
  randomForrest=    {mat<-classification_function(train, classes, type="prob")},
  svm =  { mat<-classification_function(train, classes, probabilities = T)  },
  stop("You did not pick randomForrest or svm")
 )
return(mat)
}
```

**Edit:** Added the `stop` line that gives an error message if neither choice is selected. After you designate all of the options (e.g. `svm=`) you can add a final line to be executed if there are no prior matches.

Comment: +1 - not necessarily for the use of `switch`, but I can name a few functions that use that type of character input. Often, the argument is named `method` and the list of accepted values provided as a default value, see `optim()` and its use of `match.arg()` for example. This in IMHO the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the `formals` function to determine which arguments the function is expecting, then call it accordingly.  Also see `do.call` for a way to dynamically create a function call and call it.